# Grey Out unselected items in a p:selectOneRadio

Tags: primefaces

I have been thinking about this for a while but can not think of a good way to do it. But if I am given a select one radio button list is there a good way to grey out all of the non selected radio buttons if and only if there is a value selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its more an general idea than an answer (although it should work)...

look at the generated code of selectonemenu in the show case [SelectOneRadio](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/selectOneRadio.jsf) , it creates divs , one div for radio and 1 for the label , you can use jquery selectors for tracking all the divs (radio) that are not selected (got `ui-state-default` class) and access their labels using jquery next() selector (to access the unselected radio labels) , that way you can access all the needed elements and add lower their opacity to 0.5 (for example)

I guess you can place the js code into a function that will be called by `onsuccess` of `p:ajax` that you will add to `p:selectOneRadio` or in jquery ready function(if you detect that there is a value selected already on page load)